# How to Submit an Anonymous Infopath Form to Sharepoint library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I am have my administrator approved InfoPath form uploaded to my site collection via CA and approved.  I attached the form to my SharePoint site through a web part and I am able to see it as an anonymous user. But, I am unable to submit the form data to my SharePoint library as an anonymous user.  Within the library I gave anonymous users permissions to add items and view items in the libray.

I followed some sites and tried adding custom code to submit, but I get:
There has been a critical error while processing the form....

Using the rule on the button to call the data connection, I get:
The form cannot be submitted to the specified SharePoint list or document library. The SharePoint location may be read-only or you may not have permissions to access it.
An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  When I log into the SharePoint site, submit is working fine.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this delegate

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
//yoursubmitcode
});
```